# Left Join to another select statement

Tags: mysql

I have an `INNER JOIN` query that runs perfectly fine by itself, which I want to `LEFT JOIN` to a another query/`SELECT` statement which contains WHERE clause.
I'm not able to join both the queries. It should link `wt.tkinit = t.tkinit`
Can you please suggest what I'm missing.

```
SELECT c.clnum, m.mmatter, ot.tkinit AS 'otkinit', wt.tkinit AS 'wtikint', t.tkrt01,
SUM(mt.mthrwkdb) AS 'whrs2010',
FROM client c, matter m, timekeep ot, timekeep wt, mattimhs mt, periodt p, timerate t
WHERE c.clnum = m.mclient
AND m.mmatter = mt.mtmatter
GROUP BY c.clnum, m.mmatter, ot.tkinit, wt.tkinit

SELECT t.tkinit, t.tkrt01
FROM timerate t
INNER JOIN (
SELECT tkinit, max(tkeffdate) as max_effdate 
FROM timerate WHERE DATEPART(year, tkeffdate) = '2012'
GROUP BY tkinit) mt ON mt.tkinit = t.tkinit AND mt.max_effdate = t.tkeffdate
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the following:

```
SELECT fields from (SELECT1) s1 
  LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT2) s2 
  on s1.wt.tkinit = s2.t.tkinit.
```

Don't forget to get normal name for wt.tkinit and t.tkinit in their selects like wt_tkinit and t_tkinit because you can't do double aliases.

Comment: sorry no luck. What is that s1 and s2 represent. temp table?

Comment: This is your two queries. Put it instead of SELECT1 and SELECT2

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT temp2.tkinit, temp2.tkrt01, temp.clnum, temp.mmatter, temp.otkinit, temp.tkrt01, temp.whrs2010
FROM
    ( SELECT c.clnum, m.mmatter, ot.tkinit AS 'otkinit', wt.tkinit AS 'wtikint', t.tkrt01,
    SUM(mt.mthrwkdb) AS 'whrs2010',
    FROM client c, matter m, timekeep ot, timekeep wt, mattimhs mt, periodt p, timerate t
    WHERE c.clnum = m.mclient
    AND m.mmatter = mt.mtmatter
    GROUP BY c.clnum, m.mmatter, ot.tkinit, wt.tkinit ) temp
LEFT JOIN 
    SELECT t.tkinit, t.tkrt01
    FROM timerate t
    INNER JOIN (
    SELECT tkinit, max(tkeffdate) as max_effdate 
    FROM timerate WHERE DATEPART(year, tkeffdate) = '2012'
    GROUP BY tkinit) mt ON mt.tkinit = t.tkinit AND mt.max_effdate = t.tkeffdate ) temp2
ON temp.wtikint = temp2.tkinit
```

Be careful of your field names, but this may be a start

Comment: I'm getting this erroe message

Comment: Check your field names